# ANDROID TO PROVIDE SENSOR EVENT VALUE ON CLICK (single value)

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

i tried to get orientation angle using sensormanager on event of onclick of a button and the values to be added in an textview but the sensor value updated each nano seconds on user interface. can you help to create a code to have sensor event vale at particular timestamp.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? Otherwise I'd recommend freelancer.com or Rent a Coder and pay someone to do your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of getting a single value from sensor. You will have to use a workaround:

- in the `onClick()` method, call `registerListener()` for that sensor
- in the `onSensorEventChanged()` method, call `unregisterListener()`, then update your TextView.

This will unregister from the listener after one event has been received.

Note, hovever:

- Event delivery will be asynchronous. The TextView will not have the new value yet as `onClick()` returns. Any processing relying on that needs to happen in `onSensorEventChanged()`.
- There is still a bit of a race condition as you may receive multiple events from the sensor before your code unregisters from the sensor. If that is undesired, keep track of whether you have already received an event and discard any subsequent ones.
- Sometimes sensors may be slow to deliver data (I've seen it happening). There is a chance your activity may terminate before the event gets to you, so make sure to include an extra call to `unregisterListener()` when your activity goes to the background (e.g. in `onPause()`).

Comment: Yes, though one might also consider subscribing to sensor events in advance, and remembering the last value received, so that can be used immediately in the button event.  One thing that **can't** be done is to wait in the button even for the next sensor event.

Comment: Thanks for your response but if i get array of data how can i fetch the value exactly on button click. i am struggling there to get the data and not able to solve it too.

Comment: You get an array from the orientation sensor because there are three angles: roll, pitch and yaw. If you want to fetch sensor values in advance, just define a member `mOrientation` somewhere in your Activity, do `mOrientation = event.values.clone()` when you get a sensor event, and return the values from `mOrientation` in the button event handler.